# How can I get rid of all the various database related erros of N98-magerun?

Tags: error

I wanted to test N98-magerun on my local Mac, using MAMP. I get a lot of errors, for example:

"cache:list" results in:
    [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
    [PDOException]
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

"open-browser 2"  results in the above message, plus this one:
The command terminated with an error status (2002)

"database:info" results in:
    [InvalidArgumentException]
    There are no commands defined in the "database" namespace.
    The command terminated with an error status (1)

What am I missing? I tried to google, but failed to find any useful info. Please help.

Comment: john-jh's answer solved my issue. Thank you john-jh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

N98 will be trying to use your Macs native PHP which isn't configured for MAMP's MySQL resulting in the database errors.

Change directory to /usr/bin

> cd /usr/bin

Change the name of the native php to keep a backup (just incase)

> sudo mv php php.old

Create a symlink to your php version

> sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php.[VERSION]/bin/php php

Where '[VERSION]' is your php version so you're basically creating a symlink to the PHP version you're using in MAMP

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest this method. Overriding the native php version might not be the best plan.

Update your `.bash_profile` with the following:

```
# Use MAMP version of PHP
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH

# Export MAMP MySQL executables as functions
# Makes them usable from within shell scripts (unlike an alias)
mysql() {
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql "$@"
}
mysqladmin() {
    /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin "$@"
}
export -f mysql
export -f mysqladmin
```

Solution taken from: http://www.endreywalder.com/blog/magenton98-magerunmamp/

Edit: You need to run `source ~/.bash_profile` each time you open a new Terminal, that's the only issue I have encountered.